# Error Access denied when execute Get-WSManCredSSP command using Remote PSSession

Tags: powershell, remoting, credentials, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

I have Windows XP x86, and Powershell 2.0.

I open Powershell Console, and I execute Enter-PSSession  command to connect Windows 2008 Server.

I want execute Get-WSManCredSSP command remotely, but I get error Access is denied.

```
PS C:\Documents and Settings\myuser> Enter-PSSession -Computername servermoss -Credential servermoss\installeruser

[servermoss]: PS C:\Users\installeruser\Documents> Get-WSManCredSSP -Verbose
Get-WSManCredSSP : Access is denied.
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (:) [Get-WSManCredSSP], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess,Microsoft.WSMan.Management.GetWSManCredSSPCommand

Access is denied.
    + CategoryInfo          :
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WsManError,Microsoft.WSMan.Management.GetWSManCredSSPCommand
```

SOLUTION: CredSSP not supported by WinRM 2.0 PowerShell

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, you need to `Enter-PSSession -Authentication CredSSP`, but before that `Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Client -DelegateComputer servermoss` is required on your local computer, but this doesn't work in XP. It seems WsMan CredSSP is **not** supported in XP.

Answer (score 1):

Posting this solution in case someone is still having an issue with a simple resolution to DoubleHop without using CredSSP. Haven't tried it on Windows XP yet, but might work.

Try this out:
https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Invoke-PSSession

It Invokes a PSSession, then Registers a PSSessionConfiguration with the Credentials that you provided. Basically providing the credentials for that DoubleHop

Then use Invoke-Command with that new PSSession. It should have the required privileges to do what you need.